# Transform JSON array to object with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to transform array to object by specific key. It works fine without using stream, but not possible when stream is applied.

Data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "userId": "fa51531d"
    }
    ,
    {
    "id": "2",
    "userId": "a167869a"
  }
]
```

I tried running this command but it throws an error.

> jq -n --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)) |  INDEX(.id)' test.json > result.json

Data above should be transformed to:

```
{
  "1": {
    "userId": "fa51531d",
    "id": "1"
  },
  "2": {
    "userId": "a167869a",
    "id": "2"
  },
}
```

I want to achieve the same result as with `jq 'INDEX(.id)` but I need to use stream (because of big JSON file).

Comment: Does the stream really contain the array start and end `[` ... `]` or is it a stream of objects `{ "id": "1",  "userId": "fa51531d" }` ... etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to recreate the whole input object, the stream-based approach is rendered pointless. That said, using this approach, there's no need to truncate. So either replace `1` with `0`:

```bash
jq -n --stream 'fromstream(0|truncate_stream(inputs)) | INDEX(.id)'
```

Or just omit it entirely (which reveals its futility):

```bash
jq -n --stream 'fromstream(inputs) | INDEX(.id)'
```

---

What would make more sense, is to output a stream of objects, each indexed as with `INDEX`. Maybe you were looking for this:

```bash
jq -n --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)) | {(.id):.}'
```

```json
{
  "1": {
    "id": "1",
    "userId": "fa51531d"
  }
}
{
  "2": {
    "id": "2",
    "userId": "a167869a"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pmf for reply! Unfortunately, first two solutions are fine commands but never complete (probably too big file). Last one works immediately, but I want the result in one big object and each key is in separate object. Do you have more idea how to handle it?

Comment: @wojteklu Then try to `reduce` the stream: `jq -n --stream 'reduce fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)) as $o ({}; .[$o.id] = $o)'`

Comment: @wojteklu Can you please verify that the stream really contains an array (with `[` and `]` around the individual items)? I asked the question in the comment section under your question but you never replied.

Answer (score 0):

If your stream really looks like in your question, this should do:

```
jq 'INDEX(.id)' test.json
```

Output:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "id": "1",
    "userId": "fa51531d"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "2",
    "userId": "a167869a"
  }
}
```